# maven spring - Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Tags: xml, spring, maven-2, schema, maven

I have a spring project built with the usage of maven (packaged as jar) (dependencies are copied to a separate directory and added to classpath)

I want to run it as java -jar

The problem is that when I run it I get:

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration
 of element 'beans'.

It happens because spring.schemas and spring.handlers are located in a few jars i.e.: spring-beans, etc.

Is there any way to solve it, supposing that I don't want to use shade plugin to unpack all dependencies and concatenate the content of spring.schemas and spring.handlers?

I would also like to avoid saving xsd files in my project and changing schemaLocation to point to my location.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <camel:camelContext>
        <camel:routeBuilder ref="fakeRouteBuilder"/>
    </camel:camelContext>

    <bean id="fakeRouteBuilder" class="<className>" />


</beans>
```

Comment: can you paste one of the configuration spring config files? I think the problem might be there

Comment: `<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

 <camel:camelContext>
  <camel:routeBuilder ref="fakeRouteBuilder"/>
 </camel:camelContext>

 <bean id="fakeRouteBuilder" class="com..." />

</beans>`

Comment: Check your `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute. It seems to be incorrect, but that might also be caused by the linkification of the URLs in the comments. Actually it would be better, if you edited your question by adding your previous comment as a code block (=select the code and click the `{}` button to make it appear as a code block)

Answer (score 25):

I know 2 situations where you can have this problem

- If you don't have an internet connection (behind a proxy, for instance). In that case, download the XSD, copy it next to the XML, and change the schema location to `xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans spring-beans-2.5.xsd ..."`
- If you have an internet connection / still have the problem, that's because you use different versions of Spring for the XSD and the jar.

Comment: Just had this problem testing on a local, internet-less network. First point was spot on.

Comment: Just faced the same problem, fixed with first solution ! Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I think the XSD would be part the spring jar, so shouldn't be issue.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, spring has the XSD's packaged and will not download them.

Answer (score 5):

Spring jars contain META-INF/spring.handlers and META-INF/spring.schemas files. To avoid overwriting the files when aggregating dependencies to one jar you can use maven Shade plugin:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#AppendingTransformer

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem because I was behind a proxy. I was running a Spring MVC app under Tomcat 6. Just added the following lines at the biginning of my **catalina.bat** file and that solved my problem:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dhttp.proxyHost=XXXX -Dhttp.proxyPort=YYYYY -Dhttp.proxyUser=ZZZZ -Dhttp.proxyPassword=XXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve a similar problem by clearing the xsd file from my remote resources cache, Window > Preferences > General > Network Connection > Cache

Comment: This also solved a similar problem I was having where I was getting errors after changing a project name.  Deleting all of the files in the cache and clean/rebuilding the project fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`META-INF/INDEX.LIST` file generated by the maven-assembly-plugin can also be a culprit.

Cause: a  Java bug: "ClassLoader.getResources() returns only 1 instance when using jar indexing"

Solution: disable the indexing in the assembly descriptor:

```
<indexed>false</indexed>
```

Resources:
[Spring JIRA SPR-5705](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5705)
[JDK-6957241 ClassLoader.getResources() returns only 1 instance when using jar indexing](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6957241)

Answer (score 0):

There's a `http://` too much in your XSD declaration. Try this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
```

(yours was `http://http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd`)

Comment: My mistake, I copied this by accident - in my context there wasn't "http://http://". I noticed, that the error happens when there is no internet connection. When I change the packaging to war problem disappears...

Answer (score 0):

I got that error when my XSD url pointing to different location that is different from XSD location defining in the jar file. For example, `spring-beans-3.0.xsd` instead of `spring-beans-2.5.xsd` vise-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use advice from [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?34417-cvc-elt-1-Cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-beans&p=369769#post369769) to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and I think it is caused by 2 principal reasons:

- You have different versions for spring-security dependencies and XSD file references.
- Also it could happend if you use different versions of spring common framework and spring-security.